# Discord.py Getting channel name and server name returns an error message

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am currently trying to create a discord bot that, when someone says a command it says what server and what channel they are in. I was able to do this in the past, however in the past I was using `on_message(message)` and `if message.content.startswith('$hello')`. I recently started using `@bot.command` and I'm still trying to get used to it. I tried using `message.guild.name` and `message.channel.mention` but I get an error message. `Undefined variable 'message'` I assume this is because with my old setup, in the `on_message(message)` I define message, however with my current code it doesn't seem to work.

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
botToken = token
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '#')
client = discord.Client()
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is online and ready.')
@bot.command()
async def whereAmI(ctx, *, messageContents):
    link = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_age = 300)
    message = 'You are in {message.guild.name} in the {message.channel.mention} channel with an invite link of ' + link
    await ctx.message.author.send(message)
bot.run(botToken)
```

And I am aware that it might DM the person, however I'm currently working on just my test bot before I bring the command over to my main one. If you have any better ideas please let me know. And the reason why I have the variable there is because I am planning on including the variables in the final product.

If anything doesn't make sense, let me know and I will edit it to hopefully make it more clear and give more context if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the message object, you need to use the passed-in "context" (ctx). So it would be `ctx.message.guild.name` and `ctx.message.channel.mention`. [Docs on Context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context)

On another note, Bot is a subclass of Client. So whatever Client can do, Bot can do too. You don't need a Client and Bot, just the Bot. [Docs on Bot subclass](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#bot)

Comment: With the current `async def whereAmI(ctx, *, messageContents):` command that i currently have, how would i tell it to use the passed-in context? Would i replace `@bot.command` with `@bot.command(pass_context=True)`?

Comment: You are already passing in the context. It's the ctx parameter. Context comes along with the command automatically. So no need for the `pass_context` bit :) [Docs on Commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how it should be.

```py
@bot.command()
async def whereAmI(ctx, *, messageContents):
    link = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_age = 300)
    message = f'You are in {ctx.message.guild.name} in the {ctx.message.channel.mention} channel with an invite link of ' + link
    await ctx.message.author.send(message)
```

Have a good day!